# Parity Bit Generator Webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

### JavaScript concerns

Is this the best way in jQuery to handle a button being pressed without making an HTTP req?

```
$("#input-box-form").submit( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = getParityData();
    showParityData(data);
});
```

This seems like a mess/redundant/I'm not doing it right.  How can I make it better with CSS/JavaScript?

```
$("#input-box").keyup( function(event) {
    var input_num = $("#input-box").val();
    if (input_num.match("^0b")){
        bin_num = input_num.slice(2);
        if (!(/^[0|1]+$/.test(bin_num))){
            $("#input-box-form").addClass("has-error");
            $("#generate-button").prop('disabled',true);
        } else {
            $("#input-box-form").removeClass("has-error");
            $("#generate-button").prop('disabled',false);
        }
    } else {
        bin_num = (+input_num).toString(2);
        if( input_num.length == 0 ){
            $("#input-box-form").addClass("has-error");
            $("#generate-button").prop('disabled',true);
        } else if (isNaN(bin_num)){
            $("#input-box-form").addClass("has-error");
            $("#generate-button").prop('disabled',true);

        } else {
            $("#input-box-form").removeClass("has-error");
            $("#generate-button").prop('disabled',false);
        }
    }
});
```

Edit - After talking with my friend, I re-worked the above:

```
$("#input-box").keyup( function(event) {
    var input_num = $("#input-box").val();
    if (input_num.match("^0b")){
        bin_num = input_num.slice(2);
        is_error = !(/^[0|1]+$/.test(bin_num));
    } else {
        bin_num = (+input_num).toString(2);
        is_error = isNaN(bin_num);
    }
    $("#input-box-form").toggleClass("has-error",is_error);
    $("#generate-button").prop('disabled',is_error);
});
```

Any code suggestions to make it more JavaScript-onic?

### HTML concerns

- Any improvements on bootstrap [mis]usage?
- Any suggestions on structure/naming conventions?
- Anything else missing from my html file?

### Functionality/usability

http://paritybitgenerator.com

- Is there anything confusing to the end user?
- Can I make the experience better?
- Are there any suggestions for things to add to the site?

**HTML code:**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
<title>Parity Bit Generator</title>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <h1><strong>Parity Bit Generator</strong></h1>
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" id="input-box-form" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="number">Input Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="input-box" placeholder="1234, 0b10, 0xBA">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="generate-button" disabled="true">Generate</button>
    </form>
    <div id="result-section" >
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>

<script src="parity-bit-generator.js"></script>
<script src="google-analytics.js"></script>
<script id="parity-data-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
     <div class="alert alert-success" id="alert-section" role="alert">
       <div id="input-info-section" class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-12">
               <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
               <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
               <p> {{ input_num }}  </p>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div id="parity-data-section" class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-3">
               <p><em>binary</em></p>
               <p> {{ bin_num }}  </p> 
           </div> 
           <div class="col-sm-3"> 
               <p><em>count of 1s</em></p> 
               <p class="large"> {{ count_of_1s }}  </p> 
           </div> 
           <div class="col-sm-3"> 
               <p><em>even parity</em></p> 
               <p> {{ even_parity }} </p> 
           </div> 
           <div class="col-sm-3"> 
               <p><em>odd parity</em></p> 
               <p> {{ odd_parity }}  </p> 
           </div> 
       </div> 
     </div>  
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function getParityData(){
    var data = {};
    data.input_num = $("#input-box").val();
    if (data.input_num.match("^0b")){
        data.bin_num = data.input_num.slice(2);
    } else {
        data.bin_num = parseInt(data.input_num).toString(2);
    }
    data.count_of_1s = data.bin_num.match(/1/g).length;
    data.even_parity = data.count_of_1s % 2;
    data.odd_parity = (data.count_of_1s + 1) % 2;
    return data;
}

function showParityData(data){
    var source = $("#parity-data-template").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var html = template(data);
    $("#result-section").html(html);
    $("#result-section").fadeIn('fast');
}

$("#input-box").bind('input',function(event) {
        $("#result-section").fadeOut('fast');
});

$("#input-box").keyup( function(event) {
    var input_num = $("#input-box").val();
    if (input_num.match("^0b")){
        bin_num = input_num.slice(2);
        if (!(/^[0|1]+$/.test(bin_num))){
            $("#input-box-form").addClass("has-error");
            $("#generate-button").prop('disabled',true);
        } else {
            $("#input-box-form").removeClass("has-error");
            $("#generate-button").prop('disabled',false);
        }
    } else {
        bin_num = (+input_num).toString(2);
        if( input_num.length == 0 ){
            $("#input-box-form").addClass("has-error");
            $("#generate-button").prop('disabled',true);
        } else if (isNaN(bin_num)){
            $("#input-box-form").addClass("has-error");
            $("#generate-button").prop('disabled',true);

        } else {
            $("#input-box-form").removeClass("has-error");
            $("#generate-button").prop('disabled',false);
        }
    }
});

$("#input-box-form").submit( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = getParityData();
    showParityData(data);
});
```

Comment: What's the point of `.form-group`?

Comment: Since the label is class sr-only, I guess I do not need the extra form group. I got it by just using the example straight out of the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-example) . I removed the wrapping class and it functions the same.

Answer (score 2):

This is nice! A few things I would do differently.

#### Simplify the parity calculation

Once you have the even parity, it's simpler to calculate the odd parity from it:

```
data.even_parity = data.count_of_1s % 2;
data.odd_parity = 1 - data.even_parity;
```

#### Wait for dom to be ready

You should not make jQuery calls before the page is fully loaded. Wrap all the `$(...)` calls within this:

```
$(function() {
    // ...
});
```

#### Compile the HandleBars template once, reuse many times

You are recompiling the HandleBars template on every query:

> ```
> function showParityData(data){
>     var source = $("#parity-data-template").html();
>     var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
>     var html = template(data);
>     $("#result-section").html(html);
>     $("#result-section").fadeIn('fast');
> }
> ```

When it would be enough to do only once, on page load:

```
var template;

$(function() {
  var source = $("#parity-data-template").html();
  template = Handlebars.compile(source);
});

function showParityData(data){
    var html = template(data);
    $("#result-section").html(html).fadeIn('fast');
}
```

Another small thing here, notice that I chained the `.fadeIn` on the `$("#result-section").html(html)`, it's less duplication, and more efficient this way because jQuery won't have to repeat the same dom query again.

#### Usability concerns

I don't like that every keypress in the input field clears the output. I like to see the previous output even while I'm typing. So I would comment out this bit:

```
$("#input-box").bind('input',function(event) {
    $("#result-section").fadeOut('fast');
});
```

I would like it more if the input received focus on page load, so I can just start typing. You could chain `.focus()` after any of the queries on `$("#input-box")`, for example:

```
$("#input-box").keyup(function(event) {
    // ...
}).focus();
```

It might be also nice if you could parameterize the URL to show a specific number, for example:

```
// permalink to 123 with:
// http://paritybitgenerator.com/?123
$("#input-box").val(location.search.substr(1));
$("#input-box-form").submit();
```

#### Simplifying keyup

You could remove the extra parentheses:

> ```
> is_error = !(/^[0|1]+$/.test(bin_num));
> ```

and write simply:

```
is_error = ! /^[0|1]+$/.test(bin_num);
```

I don't see the significance of the `+` sign here:

> ```
> bin_num = (+input_num).toString(2);
> ```

It seems to me this is equivalent, and simpler:

```
bin_num = input_num.toString(2);
```

#### Valid HTML

The site doesn't pass validation on http://validator.w3.org/

- Change the first line of the HTML to `<!DOCTYPE html>`
- Change `disabled="true"` to `disabled` in the Generate button
- Change `for="number"` to `for="input-box"` in the `label`
- <strike>Drop the `http-equiv` meta header</strike> -- Interestingly, [the Bootstrap website](http://getbootstrap.com/) uses this too, and fails the W3C validator because of it. Strange.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I implemented all of them. I did not know about the w3 validator either.

Comment: It looks like http-equiv fails the validator, but it's needed for bootstrap, so I kept it. I used autofocus property inside the input html instead of implementing it jquery. To clarify, I'm using the (+input_num) to handle the hex/int conversion. The + is the unary operator. It will allow the toString(2) function to return NaN if the input_num is not a valid int string or hex string starting with 0x. Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: Hm, interesting, I didn't know that about bootstrap... The page seems to work fine even if I remove it. Maybe the difference is visible only in IE? As for `(+input_num).toString(2)`, you don't need that hackery because the next `isNaN` line will catch such invalid input, for example `isNaN("jack".toString(2))` is `true`.

Comment: @massover RE: `http-equiv`: in relevant IE versions, declaring `<!DOCTYPE html>` will automatically set IE to render in edge mode.

Comment: @Schism Interestingly, the bootstrap homepage itself uses it, and it fails the w3c validator as a consequence http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: @janos: 
var invalid_input_num = '0xZSSQ';
bin_num = (invalid_input_num).toString(2);
< bin_num = '0xZSSQ', It ignores the conversion and returns the input string.

var invalid_input_num = '0xZSSQ';
bin_num = (+invalid_input_num).toString(2);
< bin_num = NaN, I test for NaN to know that it's invalid hex/int. I think +(invalid_input_num) is the same as parseInt(invalid_input_num)

Comment: @massover `isNaN('ZSSQ')` gives me `true` in Chrome. And I use the code as in my post, with the `+` removed, and it works correctly. For you it doesn't?

Comment: @janos -- ignore anything i mentioned about the +. i was wrong. i'm not sure why i used the (+input_num). it works fine without it. thanks!